# remote api GAE/J: StackOverflowError?

Tags: google-app-engine, remoteapi

I'm trying to query the datastore of one of my GAE/J application from another GAE/J app 
but I got this error using development server and also in production

Error for /servlet_url

```
   java.lang.StackOverflowError 
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.getEntry(ThreadLocal.java:381) 
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:261) 
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:146) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.getDelegate(Thread LocalDelegate.java:32) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.makeSyncCall(Threa dLocalDelegate.java:41) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.HostedRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(H ostedRemoteApiDelegate.java:45) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.makeSyncCall(Threa dLocalDelegate.java:41) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.HostedRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(H ostedRemoteApiDelegate.java:45) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.makeSyncCall(Threa dLocalDelegate.java:41) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.HostedRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(H ostedRemoteApiDelegate.java:45) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.makeSyncCall(Threa dLocalDelegate.java:41) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.HostedRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(H ostedRemoteApiDelegate.java:45) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.makeSyncCall(Threa dLocalDelegate.java:41) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.HostedRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(H ostedRemoteApiDelegate.java:45) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.ThreadLocalDelegate.makeSyncCall(Threa dLocalDelegate.java:41) 
        at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.HostedRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(H ostedRemoteApiDelegate.java:45)
```

When checking the appstats of the first application after many remote requests, I see several successful queries to /remote_api but with no RPC call

*2011-11-02 23:22:59.298 "GET remote_api" 200 real=0ms cpu=0ms api=0ms overhead=0ms (0 RPCs)*

PS: I followed extatly the steps described here:
http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in RemoteAPI: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6349